# Cross platform open source third party library for WebServices

Tags: c++, web-services

I'm looking for cross platform open source third party library for web services which support c++. I have generated c++ files using WSMakeStubs utility but it uses Core Foundation data types. I want a library which provide web service call through c++ so that I can use it on Windows and Mac both the platform. 
I wanted stubs that can be used on both Windows and Mac platform.

Could any one suggest me good library.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to recommend [gSoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html). In the company I'm working at, we use it for about 7 years now (since version 2.6.0, the actual version is 2.8.3) and only made good experiences with it. Look at the [success stories](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapstories.html) to get an overview of the companies which are using it.

Related:

- [C++ and SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086/c-and-soap)
- [What is a good platform for devoloping web services in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910854/what-is-a-good-platform-for-devoloping-web-services-in-c)
- [A Good C++ Library for SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450488/a-good-c-library-for-soap)

Comment: I also explored some of the libraries and found gSOAP is good but it requires commercial license.                                         Any idea about libcurl?

Comment: @Anni: That's not correct, have a look at the [answer from the gSOAP inventor Robert van Engelen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330174/what-license-do-i-need-to-use-gsoap-in-a-commercial-product/1289441#1289441): "... as long as you do NOT use wsdl2h, do NOT use the web server code, and do NOT use the UDDI code then you can use the gSOAP public license for free ...". _libcurl_ is no SOAP library.

Comment: @Anni: As I now read on the [gSOAP License page](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soaplicense.html), also the output from the _soapcpp2_ compiler is not covered by the _gSOAP public license_. I suppose you need the _soapcpp2_ compiler, in this case you will have the opportunity to select the _GPL v2_, which covers all of the gSOAP software.

Answer (score 2):

[pion](http://www.pion.org/projects/pion-network-library) is a possibility, though I don't know how it compares to gSoap or other alternatives.  I got it working an evening then got distracted with other reverse economies.  I seem to remember it having fewer dependencies of the others I researched.